# Lie derivations of algebra of smooth functions in a symplectic manifold

Tags: lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry, derivations

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a finite-dimensional symplectic manifold.  The algebra $C^\infty(M)$ of smooth functions is a Poisson algebra.  Derivations $D : C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ of the Poisson structure are naturally identified with vector fields which preserve the Poisson bivector, which in the symplectic case is equivalent to being a symplectic vector field.

In this question, I am however interested *not* in Poisson derivations, but only in Lie derivations; that is, real linear maps $D : C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ which obey
$$ D\{f,g\} = \{Df,g\} + \{f,Dg\}$$
for all $f,g \in C^\infty(M)$.  In particular, since $D$ is not necessarily a derivation of the commutative algebra structure, so that $D(fg) - (Df)g - fDg$ need not be zero, $D$ is not necessarily a vector field.

Have such Lie derivations been studied?  And, if so, where?